# Backup e Restaurar Backup Android

Tags: android, sqlite

Criei uma aplicação com o banco de Dados SQLite.
Gostaria de colocar a função na aplicação de fazer backup e restaurar backup.

Implementei o código desse site http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/export-sqlite-data-from-your-android-device/ porem não consegui ler o arquivo, não sei se é questão de permissão. Porem, ele ainda não resolveria todo meu problema.

Comment: Eu não conheço bem o Android mas com o SQLite a melhor forma de fazer *backup* é copiando o arquivo dele. Não sei se alguém conseguirá ajudar só com estas informações.

Comment: O android é meio chato com permissões em SD mesmo, até pra incentivar os devs a usarem o recurso de backup em nuvem que já está disponivel faz tempos. A principal vantagem do backup na nuvem é que, se o usuario formatar ou trocar de aparelho, basta logar novamente na conta e todos os dados de aplicativos voltam, até o whatsapp aderiu. Veja se essa alternativa não vale mais a pena perder um tempinho estudando como funciona do que implementar backup em SD. Até porque alguns aparelhos não tem entrada SD, ai o backup é quase que inutil.

Comment: tem algum link que ja tenha lido sobre backup na nuvem do SQLite para android?

Comment: lembrando que vi um artigo, mas nao achei interessante, ja que é uma aplicação pessoal e em massa, teria que ser tipo Dropbox

Comment: Veja esse link http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html. Já adiantando, essa página da documentação ainda não possui versão em português.